# Using SWT under OSX

Tags: java, macos, swt

I try to test a simple java application with SWT under Mac OS X. I can compile the source file without any problems but if I start the program then the following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
```

The command to compile is: "javac -classpath .:swt.jar SWTHello.java"
The command to run is: "java -d64 -XstartOnFirstThread -cp .:swt.jar SWTHello"

For the SWT library there's only one current osx version on the website so I guess I couldn't download a wrong jar.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There are 32 and 64 bit versions of the current Mac SWT library - where did you download it from?

Comment: As @greg-449 already mentioned, there is a 32bit and a 64bit version of the Mac SWT library [here on the official website](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/#SWT)

Comment: I went to http://eclipse.org/swt/ and clicked the "OS X" link. On the next page there's a download link but no version selection. So I thought I had the right one.

Comment: @altralaser Yeah, that's a bit misleading. Did you download the correct one and try again?

Comment: Yes, I found the explicit 64bit version under your posted link and tried it a few minutes ago. It works very well. Now I have my own app that looks like the standard cocoa apps. It's great! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the SWT jar in your project classpath, You are using a 32 bits cocoa, use the 64 bits:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it worked after replacing the swt .

1. Download  swt http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64
2. Replace it on this folder of your Pentaho-ce **/data-integration/libswt/osx64**

Comment: Hi @DanielMusyoka - just wondering what this adds over the earlier answer (which explains what the issue is)?